# How to read ORC file in chunks

Tags: c++, parquet, orc

I am trying to read ORC files in chunks. I have a very large ORC file on disk (say 100GB) and very limited memory (e.g., I can buffer max 1MB data in memory). I want to scan ORC file intelligently:

1. read footer
2. get addresses of stripes
3. read first stripe's metadata (footer) and apply some filters
4. read first stripe's index
5. read first stripe's data (chunk by chunk - 1MB at a time)
6. Move to the next stripe

I have tried to use `MemoryInputStream.hh` from the ORC repo:

https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/main/c++/test/MemoryInputStream.hh

However, while reading the data, its `read` method tries to access large amounts of data (beyond 1MB).

```
    virtual void read(void* buf, uint64_t length, uint64_t offset) override {
      memcpy(buf, buffer + offset, length);
    }
```

So, is there a way to read/aceess different parts of the ORC file incrementally and with a limited in-memory buffer?

Thanks!

Comment: That seems to be a class used for testing. What if you use [`SeekableInputStream`](https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/main/c%2B%2B/src/io/InputStream.hh) or `SeekableFileInputStream`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the comment. But those interfaces/classes are not exposed for external usage no? At least I could not find a way to access those classes via interfaces inside the include dir ( https://github.com/apache/orc/tree/main/c%2B%2B/include/ )

Comment: Oh, that's too bad - I thought that looked like the perfect match.